# Reference need to add for _graphServiceClient for one drive upload in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have a requirement word to pdf in our project using Visual Studio MVC.  I have done that using httprequest with the support of azure client active directory support. It was fine, but we can upload the file till 4 MB.

To check the file upload with more than 4MB, I have tried resumable file upload code, which uses packages Microsoft.Graph. I installed it from nuget packages. Most of the sites explained the code, but I am not getting how to create the object _graphServiceClient. What is the reference that I need to include this  _graphServiceClient object?

I found but not sure that that  GraphServiceClient is the class. So I include the below code in my project :

```
GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

Can anyone help me to understand, how to include _graphServiceClient  properly in the solution? What is the reference, or anything to include, so that it works fine?

```
var uploadSession = await _graphServiceClient.Drives[driveId].Items[folderId].ItemWithPath(fileName).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();

int maxSlice = 320 * 1024;

var largeFileUpload = new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession, fileStream, maxSlice);

IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(x =>
{
    _logger.LogDebug($"Uploading large file: {x} bytes of {fileStream.Length} bytes already uploaded.");
});

UploadResult<DriveItem> uploadResult = await largeFileUpload.UploadAsync(progress);

resultDriveItem = uploadResult.ItemResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft Graph .NET SDK (NuGet package) then, try the following references:

> Install-Package Microsoft.Graph
>
> Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Auth -IncludePrerelease

Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation) for all the SDK's available.